# Divisor function and Partitions

Tags: number-theory

I have found this equation for the partitions of a positive integer. if n is a natural number and p(n) represent the number of partitions of the number n, then

\begin{equation}
p(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{floor(\frac{n}{2})} \mathscr{P}(i,n+1-2i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{P}(s,t) =  \sum_{i=1}^{ceil(\frac{t}{s})} \mathscr{P}(s-1,t-s(i-1))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{P}(0,t) = 1
\end{equation}

Will this represent a closed equation for the partitions of n? A detailed explanation is found at:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08989

Using this theorem is possible to derivate the following equation for the number divisor of a number. If d(n) is the number divisors function and if we define a vector $\overline{E_n}$ as

\begin{equation}
E_n  = A_{n,n-1}E_{n-1} + nI_n
\end{equation}
Then:
\begin{equation}
d(i) = \overline{E_n}[i] ,\;i = t(n-1)+1,\cdots ,t(n)
\end{equation}

Where,
$\overline{I_i} [k]=
  \begin{cases}
   1, & if \; k = t(i-1)+1 \\
   0, & if \; k \ne t(i-1)+1
  \end{cases}$

$
A_{\tiny{i\,j}} [k,l]= 
  \begin{cases}
   -1, & if \; k = l \\
 1, & if \; k-i = l  \\
   0, & if \; other \; cases
  \end{cases}\\
$
With $k = 1,\cdots,t(i)$; $l = 1,\cdots,t(j)$. 
t(n) =  nth tringular number. 
Also, the size of a matrix $A_{\tiny{i\,j}} $ is t(i) x t(j).
$

For example:

$
\overline{E_1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$;
$
\overline{E_2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
\textbf{2} \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{E_3} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
-2 \\
-1 \\
\textbf{2 } \\
2  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{E_4} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
2  \\
1  \\
-2 \\
-1  \\
-3 \\
\textbf{3} \\
2  \\
2  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{E_5} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
-2 \\
-1 \\
2  \\
1  \\
2 \\
-1  \\
-1  \\
-4 \\
-2 \\
\textbf{2} \\
3 \\
2  \\
2  \\
1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

with

$
A_{21} =\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$
$; 
A_{32} =\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0  & -1 &0 \\
0  & 0 & -1\\
1  & 0 & 0\\
0  & 1 & 0\\
0  & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$;
$A_{43} =\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$;

And

$
\overline{I_1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\end{bmatrix}
$;
$
\overline{I_2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{I_3} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0  \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{I_4} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
0  \\
0 \\
0  \\
0 \\
1 \\
0  \\
0  \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$;
$
\overline{I_5} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
0  \\
0  \\
0 \\
0  \\
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0  \\
0  \\
0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$

A graphical representation of the equation $E_n  = A_{n,n-1}E_{n-1} + nI_n$ is a network like this
[Network for number of divisor function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjw7P.png)
This network representation starts with the number 1 , after that we write the number 2. Below the number 2 we write all that is behind this number but with the singing change, that is, -1. And we repeat this mechanism of building this network. Then, the divisor of a number, like 5, is obtained only by the sum of the numbers that are in a distance 5 starting from 1, that is, d(5) = 5 + (-1) + (-2) = 2.

Comment: Not quite clear. Do you mean that we can recover the integer  $n$ uniquely, if we know the number of divisors and the divisor sum ?

Comment: Hi Peter, that i mean is that we can obtain the number of divisor of n only with the sum of the values in this network image posted. This network has a order, somehitng like a self-similarity.

Comment: For example, if you check the imagen attached, the divisor of 5 is  d(5) = 5 + (-1) + (-2) = 2 . The numbers 5, -1 and -2 are part of this network and are all this at the same distance from the number 1 in the start of the network. There are also another network called a sum of divisor network, and also using this network we can get the sum of divisor of a number n as similar as in the case of the number of divisor network

Comment: The relationships between the integer partition function $p(n)$ and the divisor function $\sigma_1(n)$ are given in formulas (2) and (3) at the answer I posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4067159 which also provides some reference links.
.